# impossible to display value from DB

Tags: sql, pdo, connection

I change php code for my site because i need to use more security. i read a lot of message about this i do the same from the examples but unfortunatly it doesn't work. no results from database, no errors

**Before (worked fine)**

Connection php

```
<?php
try { 
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=belam647807; charset=utf8','root','root'); }
catch(Exception $e) {die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());}
?>
```

Select code

```
<?php $nbPage = ceil($total/$perPage);

if(isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page']) &&  ctype_digit($_GET['page']) == 1){
if ($_GET['page'] > $nbPage) {
  $page = $nbPage;
}else{
  $page = $_GET['page'];
}

}else{

 $page = 1;
}

$first = ($page-1)*$perPage;


$reponse = $db->query("SELECT * FROM profils ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT    $first, $perPage" );
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{
?>
```

**After change for PDO**

Connection php

```
<?php


$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test, charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

?>
```

Select code

```
<?php $nbPage = ceil($total/$perPage);

if(isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page']) && ctype_digit($_GET['page']) == 1){
if ($_GET['page'] > $nbPage) {
  $page = $nbPage;
}else{
  $page = $_GET['page'];
}

}else{

$page = 1;
}

$first = ($page-1)*$perPage;

$reponse = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM profils ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $first, $perPage" );
$reponse->execute();
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>
```

Comment: And how is this code failing?  Are there any errors in your PHP logs?  When you debug, what specifically is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the variables from the prepare statement and bind the values.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM profils ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :first, :perPage";
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(':first', $first);
$sth->bindValue(':perPage', $perPage);

if ($sth->execute()) {
    if ($sth->rowCount() > 0) {
        $data = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, i tried it but i have a blank page